# How to iterate and extract text from a container of paragraph tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble extracting text stored in some paragraph tags. I want to iterate through the tags with a 'for' loop and pull them out and combine them into one string called 'text' and then alert it. I'm pretty sure I have most of the set up correct, but what am I missing?

```
<div id = "myDiv">
<p> This is the first paragraph tag in the div.</p>
<p> I will try to loop through this div tag.</p>
<p> In order to get all of the elements used.</p>
<p> As well as the text in this div.</p>
</div>

<script>

var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var pTags = myDiv.childNodes;
var text = ' ';

//creating iterator for pTags
for (var i = 0; i < pTags.length; i++;){

//check for nodeType == text type

    if (pTags[i].nodeType == 3){

//combine nodevalue to one string

        text += pTags[i].nodeValue;
        }
}
//alert said string

alert(text);
</script>
```

I would like to combine all of the paragraphs into one single string and then alert that string or do something with the string. My assignment is to take all of these tags and do something with the text that is stored.

Comment: i think you can just do  document.getElementById("myDiv").textContent

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Firstly there is an error here: `for (var i = 0; i < pTags.length; i++;){ ` (you should remove the last ';'). After that, you should replace `pTags[i].nodeValue` with `pTags[i].textContent`

Comment: I tried what you said, but it ended up with an empty string >.<

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of the `textContent` of all the `<p>`s directly inside `#myDiv` with the query string `#myDiv > p`, and by using its second parameter to map every node to its textContent. Then, just join that array by whatever separator you want:

```js
const arrOfPTexts = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('#myDiv > p'),
  ({ textContent }) => textContent
);
const text = arrOfPTexts.join(' ');
console.log(text);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <p> This is the first paragraph tag in the div.</p>
  <p> I will try to loop through this div tag.</p>
  <p> In order to get all of the elements used.</p>
  <p> As well as the text in this div.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I'm unfamiliar with the querySelector method. I will have to look into it to understand this. Thank you!

Comment: `querySelectorAll` just selects all tags matching a particular selector string - it uses the exact same syntax and logic as in CSS.

Comment: if you don't mind, could you explain the " , ({textContent}) => textContent);" part?
How does that connect with the creation of the array? im assuming it has something to do with setting what is being stored in the array by pointing to the textContent of the P tags.?

Comment: The second parameter of `Array.from` is an optional mapping function to perform on the array-like first parameter, before resolving to the outer `arrOfPTexts`. `({ textContent })` extracts the `textContent` property of the element, and returns it - this means that the resulting array is an array of the `textContent` values, rather than an array of elements. Another way: `p => p.textContent`

Answer (score 0):

this one is enough

```js
alert(document.getElementById('myDiv').innerText);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <p> This is the first paragraph tag in the div.</p>
  <p> I will try to loop through this div tag.</p>
  <p> In order to get all of the elements used.</p>
  <p> As well as the text in this div.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm assuming innerText gets all text within the element being selected? Ill have to try this. Thank you!

Comment: you can just by running Run Code SNippet up there :D and yes it does its slightly different fro myour example though since it has new lines but you cna .replace ("\n","") them